# Detecting or triggering event when elements are within a certain area in its parent

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, listener, dom-events

In a **div** with **overflow-y** set to **scroll** (only part of it is visible) there will be **key elements** (in this case **divs**) of **varying heights**. my plan is to ping the server every time each of these key elements come into view.

Example: the **parent div** is **1000px** tall but only the area between **80px and 420px** are actually visible. there will be inside about **30** other key divs of **unpredictable** heights. for the sake of example let's say I need to ping the server when the **entire key div #27 is between the 80th and 420th pixel of its parent**.

I had the idea of storing the heights of all the child divs in a global array for use later but it didn't seem the smartest choice. I am really not sure how to trigger an event in this scenario. If it's a listener, who should listen and for what?

What is the best approach to accomplish this? I am happy with either jQuery or pure JavaScript.

Comment: You can bind a method to `$("#container-div").on('scroll'` and check whether `.position().top + .height` of each div is greater than the `.scrollTop` of the parent div, but less than scrollTop + height (420px).  Are you only worried about vertical or also horizontal?

Comment: that was my first idea. I'd make it loop through all the divs and check if each one of them had its "head" and "foot" within the visible part of the parent. my concern with this approach is about processing power as I'd imagine the machine wouldn't stop looping until the user stopped scrolling or am I wrong?

Comment: Well it depends on how many of those divs you have.  Have you tried it out to see if it works?

Comment: as I expected the machine will run the loop every time the div is scrolled. I can't say exactly how many times but it seems to be as little as 1 pixel. and the div isn't scrolling as smoothly as it was before. and right now I only have 8 child divs but it may go over a 100 in real life situations.

Comment: Instead of doing it on every scroll event you can do it on a timer perhaps; like set a timeout for 100 MS on scroll and clear it on scroll as well (so it will happen at most once every 100 MS).  Other than that, we can work on making the code more efficient, but there may be an upper bound for that.

Comment: as each child DIV has its own ID I wonder if it would be possible for each one of them to also have its on event trigger which would constantly check for its owner's position and once it was within the right range execute a function.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would be any more efficient .. if anything, it would be worse.  If the div positions don't ever change, or only change on resize, you can check against an array of their bottom positions instead.  Checking against an array of ints should be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

**For anyone needing a solution to similar problem...**

I got it working by storing the IDs of the DIVs I want to monitor in an associative array and attaching an event handler to the parent DIV with `.on("scroll", function)`.

Every time the user scrolls the parent DIV it will loop through the array to check if the position of the child's bottom border ( `$("#childdiv").position().top + $("#childdiv").height()`) is lower than the parent DIV's height (to make sure the entire DIV is visible).

I also found wise to remove the item from the array with `delete Array[id];` and execute the action I wanted.

If anyone has a better idea I would love to hear.

Comment: [Moved from Question edit to  answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que).